# Migration from JBoss 4 to JBoss 6. What to concider?

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I'm trying to deploy my application in `JBoss AS 6`. Currently it is deployed in `JBoss version 4`.

So what are the things I need to consider when doing this?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Jboss EAP 6 or Jboss AS 6? I have experience with EAP but not AS.

Comment: What are the errors you get?

Comment: @Omoro : It's jboss AS 6.

Comment: @Chann: errors ahanne hariyata fix karanna dannawa wage, ane nikan yanda chann yanda :P

Comment: @thilinarmtb, ado owa dan apata wada nemey ah...

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about two major versions change, so, expect a lot of things to happen. Some steps that might be helpful:

- Make an inventory of everything that is JBoss-specific in your project: deployment descriptors being the most common examples, but you might also be implementing some specific classes for your own use, or things like that
- Make an inventory of the Java EE APIs that you are using. For instance, JPA 1.0, JSP 1.1 and so on. With those, compare with the APIs that are available for AS 6. I guess that most of your work will be centered here.
- You might also want to take note of changes in the Java version (AS 4 was released during the days of Java SE 5, IIRC).
- Finally, you might want to take a look at the [Windup project](http://windup.jboss.org/), which is a tool that can help you migrate your applications to JBoss AS. Note, however, that it will not give you a comprehensive list of everything you need to do, but will certainly give you good hints.

One last comment: you might want to consider migrating to JBoss EAP 6, which is JBoss AS 7, or even migrating to Wildfly 8 (the successor of JBoss AS 7).

Comment: Is windup capable of providing migration assistance from JBoss 4.0 to wild fly?

Comment: JBoss AS 4.x to Wildfly 8.x are 4 major versions change. I doubt that it would every be possible :-)